# Angular 4, Test service function call, TypeError: xxxx is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service

I am trying to test a service I created in Angular 4, which is implemented as follows:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {OrderPackageResponse} from '../model/order-package-response';
import {BasketStoreHandler} from './basket-store-handler';

@Injectable()

export class OrderPackageBasketPopulator {

    private basket: BasketStoreHandler;

    constructor(private basketStoreHandler: BasketStoreHandler) {
        this.basket = basketStoreHandler;
    }

    public populateBasketWithOrderPackageResponse(
        orderPackageResponse: OrderPackageResponse
    ): void {
        // ---------------------------------
        // The function implementation
        // ---------------------------------
    }
}
```

And the test goes as follows:

```
import {OrderPackageBasketPopulator} from './order-package-basket-populator';
import {async, TestBed, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {MockBasketStoreHandler} from '../test-mocks';
import {BasketStoreHandler} from './basket-store-handler';

describe('OrderPackageBasketPopulator', () => {

    let basketPopulator: OrderPackageBasketPopulator;
    let basketStoreHandler: BasketStoreHandler;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                OrderPackageBasketPopulator,
                {
                    provide: BasketStoreHandler, 
                    useClass: MockBasketStoreHandler
                }
            ]
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject([OrderPackageBasketPopulator, BasketStoreHandler],
        (
            populator: OrderPackageBasketPopulator, 
            storeHandler: BasketStoreHandler) => {
                basketPopulator = populator;
                basketStoreHandler = storeHandler;
        }
    ));

    it('should create', async(() => {
        // ---------------------------
        // This test works
        // ---------------------------
        expect(basketPopulator).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('should populate basket with response', async(() => {           
        // ---------------------------
        // Assume 'response' is already initialized
        // ---------------------------
        // This call raises 'function populateBasketWithOrderPackageResponse not defined'
        // ---------------------------
        basketPopulator.populateBasketWithOrderPackageResponse(response);
    }));
});
```

The second test raises the error:
    TypeError: this.basketStoreHandler.updateBasket is not a function.

It looks like the service is somehow not defined, although the first test passes. Am I missing some initialization?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Apparently this is just incorrect. I'm keeping it up so someone doesn't post the exact same answer**

**I might have misunderstood the question. I am assuming BasketStoreHandler is an injectable element**

The problem is the way you are injecting the BasketStoreHandler. You'll notice in [the official angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) that if you inject a variable in the constructor

```
Constructor(private service: InjectableService)
```

You don't need to manually set equality to an internal element. Try removing the lines

```
private basket: BasketStoreHandler;
this.basketStoreHandler=basketStoreHandler
```

And see if that makes a difference.

Additionally, not that it matters, but in typescript the [public modifier is the default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Comment: Yes, `BasketStoreHandler` is an injectable element too

Comment: Nope, removing those lines didn't make the difference, although looks much neater now :)